# On $p$ subgroup of automorphisms of infinite abelian $p$ group

Tags: group-theory, p-groups, infinite-groups

**Problem**:
Let $A$ be an infinite abelian group. Assume that order of every element of $A$ is power of $p$.
Let G be a finite $p$ subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}A$, and
$$ A^G = \{a \in A \mid a = g(a), \forall g \in G \} . $$
Show that $\lvert A^G \rvert > 1$.

**Attempt**:
If $A$ is finite, it is easily proven.
So, if there exits finite subgoup of $A$ (call it $B$), and $g(B) = B$ for all $g \in G$, it is done ($\{1\} \subsetneq B^G \subseteq A^G$).

**Question**:
Does such subgroup $B$ always exist? Or, anothe way to solve the problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The first part of this answer answers the original question when $A$ was assumed finite, the second part answers the new version.**

The group $G$ acts on the set $A$. There is a trivial orbit $\{Id\}$, where $Id$ is the identity element of $A$, all orbits have lengths powers of $p$ since $|G|$ is a power of $p$. The sum of all lengths is $|A|$, a power of $p$. Hence there should be another trivial orbit $\{x\}$, hence $Id\ne x\in A^G$, and $|A^G|\ge 2$.

**An answer to the new version.** Take $Id\ne a\in A$. Then the orbit $G\cdot a$ of $a$ under the action of $G$ is finite. Let $A_1$ be the subgroup generated by that orbit. Then $A_1$ is finite because $A$ is locally finite (being Abelian and torsion). Moreover $A_1$ is a finite $p$-group since all its elements have orders powers of $p$. The group $G$ acts on $A_1$. By the previous argument $|A_1^G|\ge 2$, Q.E.D. since $A_1^G\subset A^G$.

Comment: I forgot to write "$A$ if an infinite group" (I'm sorry...). I think that in the case of $\lvert A \rvert = \infty$, arguments about $\lvert A\rvert$ is invalid.

Comment: I included a proof of the new version.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $G$ is finite, but I cannot see that assumption in the question.

Comment: @DerekHolt: The original version and the current version of the question are different. My answer answers both.

Comment: @DerekHolt I assumed that $G$ is finite (I'll edit my question). By the way, it is interesting if the statement still holds in the case of $\lvert G\rvert = \infty$

Comment: @2Bn2B: It is in my answer (the second part). Did you post this comment now or 21 hours ago?

Comment: @markvs I said "$A$ is infinite" in the first comment, and "$G$ is finite" in the last comment. Your second solution indeed answers what I wanted to know.

Comment: If $G$ is also infinite, then the statement is false. For example, $G=\Bbb Z$ acts on the **direct** product $A$ of countable number of copies of $\Bbb Z_2$ indexed by integers by shifting to the left. But $A^G$ has only one point, $1$. 

Similarly, you can take any infinite group $G$ with law $x^p=1$ and make it act on the direct product of copies of $\Bbb Z_2$ indexed by elements of $G$.

Comment: But ${\mathbb Z}$ is not a $p$-group, so that is not a counterexample. There are some very wild infinite $p$-groups, such as Tarski Monsters, and I would be surprised if the statement was true for them.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I wrote "Similarly, you can take any infinite group $G$ with law $x^p=1$ and make it act on the direct product of copies of $\Bbb Z_2$ indexed by elements of $G$." Since $G$ does not have to be finitely generated, you do not really need Tarski monsters. The statement is that $\Bbb Z_2\wr G$ has no central elements in $\Bbb Z_2^G$.